# How to Detect and Connect to the 3G network via ipad programatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, 3g-network

I want to use the 3G network connectivity, to send data over server, currently I am using the **iOS Developer Library - Reachability**, through which i can detect and connect the WiFi network and it is working fine for me.

But now I want to use the 3G network to do the same.

Can anyone help me out to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reachability extension [http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24] by Andrew Donoho can help you detect when your app is connected via WWAN